# How to plot Japanese string-based data in Python

Tags: python, string, python-ggplot, morphological-analysis

**I have a csv like this:**

```
Date, i, eat, chicken, you, fish, banana
2014-9-14, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0
2014-10-15, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0
2014-11-13, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1
```

Forget about upper/lowercase and stemming because I will be morphological analyzing Japanese texts.

*Ultimate Goal:*

http://imgur.com/uyTRQXR (I do not have enough reputation to post images.)

*Note:* Y-axis is the word counts. It doesn't have to be a dot, x, square and some random shapes, just dots/x with different colors will be fine.

I want to use ggplot instead of matplotlib if possible.

Comment: How to decide `eat` on `2014-09-14` at a scale of 2

Comment: @Wazzzy There are two 'eat' in the sentence of 'I eat* chicken, you eat* chicken', there has been some mistakes on the mData, will correct it now, sorry.

Comment: Mistake: I eat chicken, you eat fish.

Comment: So what's your question? Is it how to plot a date vs. frequency scatterplot with custom icons, or how to do word counts that output that .csv? If both, then please separate this into two separate questions.

Comment: @Adam redefined question.

Comment: I can't see the relevance of these numbers being word counts in a Japanese text to the question in its current form. I suggest removing irrelevant information.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for a form of [scatter plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_plot). The [first example on the ggplot project page](https://github.com/yhat/ggplot#examples) shows an how to configure one.

The data should already be in the form which you need for the plot. In your case, you probably should omit the `stat_smooth()` since the words aren't really correlated.